# Using Bootstrap Modals in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to have a form that allows users to check a status in our DB, and on submit I want write to our db, and then return a bootstrap css modal that has their info from querying another table in the db.  All works great except the modal, it just loads the div without creating the pop-up panel.  I am assuming I am not loading a dependency library that it needs but still learning so figured I'd see feedback on my code and any potential solutions.

My code is:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<style>
  form { margin:0 auto; }
  input { display:block; }
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
<form id="LiRoForm">
<div class="page-header">
I have a an image header here
</div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name..">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control validate[required,custom[email]]" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email..">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Application ID:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="appID" name="appID" placeholder="Please enter the full application ID">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg" id="submit-button" value="Check Status" 
           onclick="submitForm(); return false;">
           </form>
</div>

<div id="dialog" title="Modal Title" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog" aria-hidden="true"></div>


<script>    
    function submitForm() {
        var form = $('#LiRoForm')[0];
checkForm(function(){
            $("#submit-button")[0].value = 'Checking Status...';


            google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(function onSuccess(data) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (data == '') {
                        $("#dialog").html("<div>Our records indicate you have no data in the system</div>");


                    }
                    else {
                        $("#dialog").html("<div>Our system indicates you have the following data:</div>");
                        for(var x in data) {
                            $("#dialog").append("<div>"+data[x].FileType+"</div>");
                        }

                    }
                $("#submit-button")[0].value = 'Check Status';
                $("#dialog").modal('show');


            })
            .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
                alert(error);
            })
            .checkStatus(form);

            });



    }

    function checkForm(callback) {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var appID = $('#appID').val();
        var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;

        if (name == '' || email == '' || appID == '' || fileType == '') {
            alert("Please fill in all fields");
            return;
        }
        else if (file == '') {
             alert("Please select a file");
             return;
        }
        else if (emailPattern.test(email) == false) {
            alert("Please enter a valid email address");
            return;
        }

        // Validate AppID
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(callback)
        .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
            alert(error);
        })
        .checkID(appID);
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Clarification, please. That code isn't enough to reproduce your problem, it's missing all the GS, notably how you're loading & showing the HTML (... what sandboxing model), `checkID()` & `checkStatus()`. Probably best if you strip it down to the minimum required to demonstrate the failure you're describing, if you want answers that are better than guesses. (Are you intending to have an IFRAME sandbox generate a pop-up from a cross-domain script? If so, your problem might be Google's security model.)

Comment: I would debug starting from the successHandler.  Are you getting data back?  Is the new HTML being injected into the DIV?  How do you know?  Are you stepping through lines of code in a browser development tool?  [debugger;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)

Comment: Yes new data is being injected into the DIV and the checkID() and check status functions continue to work (). I have a stripped down version here so that it can be seen:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbztZook-TNui3xcNEaAb5lq8EpUu8a0mz1FgM6FSg4UhTF0DDAu/exec

Comment: Update: I switched the sandbox mode to IFRAME and the pop-up works, with one glitch.  The popup does not come up-on top of the grey background.  Example can be seen here: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbztZook-TNui3xcNEaAb5lq8EpUu8a0mz1FgM6FSg4UhTF0DDAu/exec


GS:
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page.html')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Mogsdad switching the html mode from NATIVE to IFRAME was the solution, as well as matching up that the style css and bootstrap scripts matched up:

Not Working:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Working

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How do you switch the html mode from Native to iframe?